# Integrating React app with Xero API using OAuth 2.0

Tags: reactjs, frontend, single-page-application, xero-api

Created a new app a developer Xero account. From the App, I got client_id and a callback. This is a dotnet core project integrating Xero SDK.

I created a simple HTML using the following code and that works nicely. (same as they provided [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/sign-in))

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="xero-client-id" content="42xxxx">
    <meta name="xero-scopes" content="openid,profile,email">
    <meta name="xero-redirect-uri" content="host-url/oidc-signin">
    <title>My App </title>
</head>
<body>
    <span data-xero-sso data-label="Sign in with Xero"></span>
    <script src="https://edge.xero.com/platform/sso/xero-sso.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a React application, I'm adding a button within a react app so that user can authenticate and then get the invoices from Xero. So the button is not working from the react app. When I click on the button nothing just happens.

Any idea, please?

I found [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-openidconnect) and tried but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am having this problem as well